# How to defeat the Shadow of Modremoth

Tags: guild-wars-2

So in the latest episode of the current living story episode (s2p3e8 Point of no return) there is a boss battle.

> Against the Shadow of Modremoth, after you learn Wynnes secret

In the second round of this fight you have to light fires using the divine fire buff, whilst avoiding the AoE and also doing it quick enough the that invincible minion doesn't go and eat all your fires.

I am playing as [Ranger](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Ranger) and the most I can manage at a time is 2/5 required fires. I am using [Rampage as One](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Rampage_As_One) for the [Swiftness](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Swiftness) and [Stability](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Stability) along with Sword/Horn + Longbow for [Call of the Wild](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Call_of_the_Wild) to get Swiftness.

What skills, traits and techniques will help me win this encounter? Should my tactics focus on mobility, stun breaks (to break from knockdown) and stability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those minions aren't "invincible".

> All you have to do is get the divine fire buff and hit them, which should be easy for a ranger (especially with the trait [Eagle Eye](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Eagle_Eye) and a longbow, giving you range 1500).

That way, your fires will stay lit and getting all 5 lit is just a matter of getting those shadows as soon as they appear. The only thing making this a bit tricky is that sometimes you'll have to wait for your friends (Braham etc.) to throw the divine fire over the vines.

Enjoy the cinematic cutscene when you accept your rewards... some interesting revelations there. Apparently we'll know more within 24 hours :-)